# Unable to link changeset to work item with TFS API

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-sdk, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to create a work item and link a changeset to him in C# with [.NET client libraries for Azure DevOps Services (and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts) (the new API).

I successed to create a work item, but if I try also to link a changeset I got an error.

My code:

```
// After add title etc.
json.Add(
        new JsonPatchOperation()
        {
             Operation = Operation.Add,
             Path = "/relations/-",
             Value = new
             {
                 rel = "ArtifactLink",
                 url = {changesetUrl},
                 attributes = new
                 {
                      name = "Fixed in Changeset"
                 }
             }
       });

// then I create the work item with CreateWorkItemAsync(json, teamProject, "Task")
```

The exception:

> Invalid Resource Link Target: 'http//tfsServer:8080/tfs/collection/_apis/tfvc/changesets/{changesetID}'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to figure out where the problem was.

In the `url = {changesetUrl},` I passed in the variable the changeset url(`'http//tfsServer:8080/tfs/collection/_apis/tfvc/changesets/{changesetID}`), this url is not the correct url for this api call.

The correct url is: `vstfs:///VersionControl/Changeset/{changesetID}`.

After I changed the url it worked and the work item created with the link.